# Django rest api framework ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have **ModelSerrializer**:

```
class ProbeParamsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
modems = ModemParamsSerializer(many=True, required=True)
net_adapters = NetworkAdapterParamsSerializer(many=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = ProbeParams
    fields = (
        'probe', 'modems', 'net_adapters', 'ram_free', 'sd_free', 'num_measurement_files', 'num_audio_files',
        'cpu_t',
        'cpu_load', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'navigation_status', 'info_updated')
```

I perform:

```
probe_params_serializer = ProbeParamsSerializer(data=item)
```

Item look as:

```
{
"info_updated": 56483476,
  "config_updated": 325687,
  "ram_free": 800,
  "sd_free": 2000,
  "num_measurement_files": 8,
  "num_audio_files": 2,
  "cpu_temp": 38.7,
  "cpu_load": 58.4,
  "latitude": 0,
  "longitude": 0,
  "modems": [
```

**Note parameter: cpu_temp**.  The model is called **сpu_t** and the report comes under the same name **cpu_temp**. So naturally when performing validation, I get an error -

> "this field (**сpu_t**) is required".

I understand which is why there is an error, but I do not know how to link these two names. It is necessary to make the value of the parameter **cpu_temp**  are stored in a parameter **cpu_t**.

Help me please.

Comment: I guess you are looking for the [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) parameter which tells serializer field which model field to use.